# "Firebase is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, html, dom, firebase

I was trying out my Firebase beta invite by calling the db from the local HTML I created.
Here's the code which refused to work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://static.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myDataReference;

            function call_on_click() {
                alert("Done!");

                try {
                    myDataReference = new Firebase('https://sbose78.firebaseio.com/');
                    myDataReference.set('I am now writing data into Firebase!');
                } catch (e) {

                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="push me" onclick="call_on_click()">
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using Firefox 11 on  Ubuntu.

```
[02:40:58.766] Firebase is not defined @ file:///root/Desktop/firebase-app1.html:20
--
[02:43:28.743] file:///root/Desktop/firebase-app1.html
[02:43:28.796] GET https://static.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1766ms]
[02:43:30.572] uncaught exception: [Exception... "Operation is not supported"  code: "9" nsresult: "0x80530009 (NS_ERROR_DOM_NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR)"  location: "https://static.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js Line: 28"]
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you actually running a webserver on your machine?

Comment: No, I'm not. Sorry, do I need to ?

Comment: As far as I am aware, you do.  I'm not experiencing any problems with your code; I'm currently using xampp.  I commented out the write, though.

Comment: Try keeping the write once and comment back? 
Just wanna see the data change.

Comment: Also, why exactly should I need a server. I was wondering it could be browser issue. Also, where in the docs have they mentioned about the server?

Comment: There, executed.  As to the docs, I've seen it said before, currently trying to find something solid on it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked ! However, I wonder why the server is required :)

Comment: @Daedalus  it says on main page of Firebase website no server required

Comment: That's really weird. The internal working might throw some light. The thing worked as soon as I ran my Glassfish.

Comment: @charlietfl [What it says is that you don't need server-side components](https://www.firebase.com/how-it-works.html)(see #3).

Comment: you can't make ajax calls in some browsers from local file system. Accessing this data has to be done via akjax

Comment: @charlietfl I see you changed your reply.  Thank you for retracting the insult.  It has no place in civil discussion.

Comment: @SHOUBHIKBOSE Do neither of the answers below answer your question?

Comment: No ( sorry for this late reply. I feel its a browser issue)

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in the Firebase JavaScript client caused by the handling of sessionStorage in Firefox when loading things from a file. It should be fixed at this point.

Give it another shot and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this is an issue with the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs).  As stated at the aforementioned document:

> Starting in Gecko 1.9, files are allowed to read only certain other files.  Specifically, a file can read another file only if the parent directory of the originating file is an ancestor directory of the target file. Directories cannot be loaded this way, however.
>
> For example, if you have a file foo.html which accesses another file bar.html and you have navigated to it from the file index.html, the load will succeed only if bar.html is either in the same directory as index.html or in a directory contained within the same directory as index.html.